# How can I make a "binary process tree"?

Tags: c, process, fork

I have a number of process to create. Every son has to create two sons. I used a recursive solution, it works but the number of process created aren't what I want.

This is what I tried:

```
void generate_kid(int g, int res){
  pid_t kid1, kid2;
  int status1, status2;
  if( res > 0 ){
    if( kid1 = fork() ){
      if( res > 0){
        if( kid2 = fork() ){
        }
        else {
          printf("I am %d, my father is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
          generate_kid(g,res/2-1);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      printf("I am %d, my father is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
      generate_kid(g,res/2-1);
    }
  }
  waitpid(kid1,&status1,0);
  waitpid(kid2,&status2,0);
}
```

Comment: Show what you tried and someone will try to help you. We don't write code for you here.

Comment: sorry! this was my first question ever!

Comment: How many processes do you expect to create, and how many are you getting instead?

Comment: After the first `fork()` you test `if (res > 0)` again, even though you don't change it. Maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: "g" is the number of childs that I have to create. 
and "res" is the restants childs I've not already created.

Comment: That's not what your code does. It looks like it uses `res` as the remaining children to create, reducing it in half each time it recurses, and it doesn't do anything with `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void generate_kid(int res){
  pid_t kid1, kid2;
  int status1, status2;

  if( res > 0 ){
    if ((kid1 = fork())  == 0) {
      // child
      printf("I am %d, my father is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
      // generate half remaining rounded up for odd processes
      generate_kid((res-1)/2);
    }
    else if (kid1 > 0) {
      // parent - create second child
      if( res > 1){
        if ((kid2 = fork()) == 0) {
          // child 2
          printf("I am %d, my father is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
          // generate half remaining processes
          generate_kid((res-2)/2);
        }
        else if (kid2 > 0){
          // parent 2
          waitpid(kid2,&status2,0);
        }
      }
      waitpid(kid1,&status1,0);
    }
  }
}
```